# changing xcode build number doesn't change in appstoreconnect and remains the same 1.0

Tags: flutter, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an application in which I want to upload it to testflight, before that the:
version 1.0
build 1.0
now I have an update and when I change it to:
version 1.0
build 1.1
it uploads successfully, but in appstoreconnect, it is processing and after finishing, there is nothing showed as build 1.1, why?!

upvoting my question would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your `pubspec.yaml` & `info.plist` ?

Answer (score 2):

To update the version for the ios build, follow the following steps.

1. Change the version from `pubspec.yaml` file, as `version: 1.1.0+1`
2. Open the `ios` folder in `Xcode` and change the version, as
   [image]

3. Close Xcode and run the following commands in the terminal. `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, `cd ios`,
4. For Mac M1 `arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update`

   For Mac Intel `pod install --repo-update`

and then archive again.

Must check the version of the newer build from the Organizer Window which will automatically open after successful build or you can open the organizer by pressing `Command + Option + Shift + O`

Comment: Hello, the version in pubspec.yaml is like that (#version: 1.0.0+1), the same as you mentioned, but what does that mean? I want to understand, is this the version number or build number, and what does +1 means?
and about version and build number, I think every version has many build number, but yours is different, your build is 1 but version 1 point something, why?! 
I think about it like this = > version 1 , build: 1.0 , 1.1 , 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 ...etc 
but yours is the opposite build 1 , version: 1.0 , 1.1 , 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 ...etc 
which one is correct?!

Comment: Hey, below is the complete breakdown of the version and build numbering system.
For example: 1.0.0+1
Version: 1.0.0
Build number: +1

There are three steps in the version. Major Version, Minor Version, and Patch Version.

You change the patch version when you fix a bug. and change the minor version when you add a new feature or enhancements. and increment the major version when you make significant changes or introduce backward-incompatible features in your app.

and the build number is changed with every new build upload.
i'll explain in next comment.

Comment: You have to change the build number with every new update for the Play Store.
for example: 1.0.0+1
When you release the next version of the app you must increment the build number along with the version number. for example: 1.0.1+2, 1.0.3+3, 1.1.0+4 and so on.

but for appstore, you can reset the build number for every new version, but if you want to upload the same version to the testflight, you must have to increment the build number. for example: 1.0.0+1, 1.0.0+2, and when you change the version. 1.0.1+1, 1.0.2+1

Answer (score 0):

To control for version and build number there is two way

1. First one from xCode you can change version and build make sure this below code info.plist

   ````
   <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
   <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>

   <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
   <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>```
   ````
2. Second if you want use version and build number in yaml file  make sure below code in info.plist

   ```
   <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
   <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>

   <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
   <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
   ```

Note

`CFBundleShortVersionString` refer to version
`CFBundleVersion` refer to build number